# Intel I350 NIC randomly switches off Ethernet ports until system reboot on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, network-interface, troubleshooting

I have a Dell PowerEdge R620 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed. This system features an Intel I350 NIC.

This card had 4 Ethernet ports.

After boot or when normally running, I can plug an Ethernet cable into any of the ports, and it works fine.

After a random delay, sometimes an hour, sometimes half a day, the port switches off completely, and stops blinking entirely.

- Unplugging, and re-plugging the Ethernet cable to the same ports doesn't help.
- Moving the cable to a different port works. So the card isn't completely lost after this delay. This new port also dies after a random delay. I am then left with 2 usable ports.
- Rebooting the system brings all 4 ports back up. Using them kills the ports one by one until next reboot.

running `sudo lshw -C network` gives me the following output:

```
    *-network:0
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
        logical name: eno1
        version: 01
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=1.56, 0x800009b6, 14.0.12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
        resources: irq:55 memory:dcb00000-dcbfffff memory:dcff0000-dcff3fff memory:dc000000-dc07ffff
    *-network:1
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0.1
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
        logical name: eno2
        version: 01
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 1Gbit/s
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.56, 0x800009b6, 14.0.12 ip=192.168.1.178 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
        resources: irq:65 memory:dcc00000-dccfffff memory:dcff4000-dcff7fff memory:dc080000-dc0fffff
    *-network:2
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0.2
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
        logical name: eno3
        version: 01
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=1.56, 0x800009b6, 14.0.12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
        resources: irq:75 memory:dcd00000-dcdfffff memory:dcff8000-dcffbfff memory:dc100000-dc17ffff
    *-network:3
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0.3
        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.3
        logical name: eno4
        version: 01
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=1.56, 0x800009b6, 14.0.12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
        resources: irq:85 memory:dce00000-dcefffff memory:dcffc000-dcffffff memory:dc180000-dc1fffff
    *-network:0
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 1
        logical name: vethe154dcc
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:1
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 2
        logical name: veth43d1ef9
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:2
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 3
        logical name: veth1f9ef04
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:3
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 4
        logical name: veth9a6af7d
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:4
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 5
        logical name: br-e50fbe4bf77f
        serial: 02:42:15:23:d0:43
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
    *-network:5
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 6
        logical name: docker0
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
    *-network:6
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 7
        logical name: vethaa82509
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:7
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 8
        logical name: veth41fb182
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:8
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: 9
        logical name: vethc14b450
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:9
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: a
        logical name: veth657c987
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:10
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: b
        logical name: veth867f6b9
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
    *-network:11
        description: Ethernet interface
        physical id: c
        logical name: veth911a044
        serial: [HIDDEN]
        size: 10Gbit/s
        capabilities: ethernet physical
        configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

Updated the firmware to 19.5.12 since posting the above, the problem still exists.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I've just rebooted and saw 2 warning in the logs.

`ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist`

`Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate`

I'll let it run until it breaks again then print the logs from the next port over.